# A Non-recursive Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

How can I determine the general term of a Fibonacci Sequence? Is it possible for any one to calculate F<sub>2013</sub> and large numbers like this?
Is there a general formula for the n<sup>th</sup> term of the Fibonacci Sequence?

If there is a combinatorial formula, that is more preferable; some formula like 
F<sub>n</sub> = <sup>x</sup>C<sub>y</sub> or <sup>x</sup>P<sub>y</sub> or something like that for some x and y.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Comment: Oh, come on. 2013 is *not* large for a 5-line loop.

Answer (score 5):

It can be shown that:
$$
F_n = \mathop{round}\left(\frac{(1 + \sqrt{5})^n}{2^n \sqrt{5}}\right)
$$
but that doesn't help much, as it needs high-precision $\sqrt{5}$.

The other technique is to see that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  F_{n + 2} \\
  F_{n + 1}
\end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 1 \\
      1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
      \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
              F_{n + 1} \\
              F_n
            \end{pmatrix}
$$
so that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  F_n \\
  F_{n - 1}
\end{pmatrix}
  = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 1 \\
      1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}^{n - 1}
      \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
              1 \\
              0
            \end{pmatrix}
$$
You could compute this by diagonalizing the matrix, but that leads to the same trouble as the previous technique (not too surprisingly, the eigenvalues are precisely the troublesome irrational zeros of $z^2 - z - 1$). But if you compute the power of the matrix by an efficient exponentiation method (like [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)) you get a practical algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

From wiki:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n$

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the Fibonnaci recursion is linear , so that it can be expressed as a $2\times 2$-matrix. The matrix is diagonalizable, so that its powers have a relatively nice form.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty slick way of finding a closed form for the Fibonacci sequence through the use of generating functions.

Let $G(x)$ be the generating function corresponding to the F. sequence.  That is, we let $G(x)$ be the power series with coefficient coming form the Fibonacci sequence.  $$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n x^n = 1 + x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + \cdots.$$

Note that we are taking $F_0 = 1$.  Also it can be shown through induction that $F_n$ grows slower than $2^n$, which means that $G(x)$ has a radius of convergence of at least 1/2.

Now consider the identity: $G(x) - x G(x) - x^2 G(x) = 1$ which can be found by using the properties of the F. sequence.

This tells us that $$G(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2}.$$

Now this is where the interesting parts come in.  We can factor the denominator: into $-(x-\phi)(x-\hat\phi)$ where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\hat\phi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Then we can use partial fraction decomposition to find $A$ and $B$ for which: $$G(x) = \frac{A}{x-\phi} + \frac{B}{x+\hat\phi}$$  Now you can expand each term into a geometric series involving $\phi$ and $\hat \phi$ respectively.

Finally you equate the coefficients of $F_n$ with the new terms found in the last step and you find what tsktsktsk posted from wikipedia.

This can be done for any finite linear recurrence relation.  It's pretty darned cool.

Comment: Put $x=0.01$ into your generating function, and you find $1/0.9899=1.010203050813....$

Comment: Haha I never thought of that!  You could get longer strings with 0.001 and 0.0001 etc.  Cool stuff!

Comment: Something that should be mentioned is that even though we can find a closed form for the fibonacci sequence, the best way to calculate a term in the sequence is by using the recursion.  There are approximation problems that arise when you have to compute the golden ratio $\phi$.

Comment: @Joel You can also take the appropriate entry from $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n$, avoiding approximation problems and recursion.

Comment: Yes that is true. You can write a general formula by diagonalizing that matrix and taking powers. The generating function approach applies to a broader class of recursions, so I usually just use that. By the way, with the matrix representation you can arrive at the identity $$(-1)^n = F_{n+1}F_{n-1} - F_{n}^2$$ which is occasionally useful.

Comment: Though in the diagonalization, you would still have a squareroot of 5. This brings back the approximation issue.

Answer (score 1):

When

(1) $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_{n}$

one can try $F_n = \phi^n$, then we obtain

(2) $\phi^{n+2} - \phi^{n+1} - \phi^n = 0$,

thus

(3) $\phi^n \Big( \phi^2 - \phi - 1 \Big) = 0$,

ignoring the trivial case $F_n = 0$ we obtain

(4) $\phi = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{5}$

So we get

(5) $F_n = a \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{5} \right)^n + b \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{5} \right)^n $

As $F_0 = 0$ and $F_1 = 1$, we get

(6a) $ a + b = 0 $

(6b) $ \frac{1}{2} \Big( a + b \Big) + \frac{1}{2} \Big( a - b \Big) \sqrt{5} = 1$

So

(7a) $\displaystyle a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} $

(7b) $\displaystyle a = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} $

Then

(8) $\displaystyle F_n = \frac{ \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{5} \right)^n - \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{5} \right)^n }{\sqrt{5}} $

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a combinatoral formula

$F_{n+1}=\sum_{k=[\frac{n+1}{2}]}^{n}{kC{n-k}}$

Proof is very simple.

This formula is related to this problem:-

In how many ways a number $n$ can be represented as sum of $1$'s and $2$'s?